# jquery after filtering element "click" event gives wrong no.of console

Tags: jquery, filtering

In my page i have no.of checkboxes, i am filter them as 2 category. in case if i have the value which is equal to my server value i am adding a class.. this part 1 of element(5 elements). rest are the part 2 of elements.

in case of part 2 of element if i click, the function giving the console the number of times (which i added classes 5 times ).. what is the reason for that, and how can i avoid that..

here is my function :

```
 var sv = [];
var userLocales = $('input[type="checkbox"]', "form").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() === value["name"];
}).prop("checked", true).addClass("userLocales").on("change", function() {
    console.log($(this).prop("class"));
});
var plainLocales = $('input[type="checkbox"]', "form").filter(function() {
    return $(this).hasClass("userLocales") !== true;
}).on("change", function() {
    console.log("i am fresh"); //consoling 5 times..
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got this working in the following example, take a look and see if it solves your problem.

Example HTML:

```
<form>
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="Aus" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="US" />   
</form>
```

Example JS:

```
var serverValue  = { name: "US" };

var userLocales = $('input[type="checkbox"]', "form")
    .filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() === serverValue["name"];
    })
    .prop("checked", true)
    .addClass("userLocales").on("change", function() {
        console.log($(this).prop("class"));
    });

var plainLocales = $('input[type="checkbox"]', "form")
    .filter(function() {
        return $(this).hasClass("userLocales") !== true;
    })
    .on("change", function() {
        console.log("i am fresh");
    });
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tBArv/2)

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble interpreting your question, can you post a html snippet that this code targets so I can see what is not working?